# How to install nodejs 6.x version on centos 6?

Tags: node.js

I use centos release 6.9

current nodejs version v0.10.48

I want install nodejs 6.x version

and I try

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
yum install nodejs
```

but occur error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPjpP.png)

how to install nodejs 6.x version on centos 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is use `n` to switch the node version

To avoid some issue after version changed, please run this command.

`npm cache clean -f`

Then install `n`

`npm i -g  n`

Now, use `n` install node version you want. (I suggest you lts one.)

`n lts`

here is `n` documentation https://github.com/tj/n

Comment: Really surprised this is the first time I've seen this as a solution for node. Much better than trying to go the usual route.